# How can I get VS Code's IntelliSense to behave like GCC with respect to pre-defines?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

If I compile and run the following program with gcc, it prints "Defined". However, in VS Code with the C/C++ extension, the line with `printf` is greyed out, suggesting it won't be executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <features.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #ifdef __USE_MISC
    printf("%s\n", "Defined");
    #endif
}
```

I tried getting gcc to output its pre-defines with `gcc -E -dM main.c`, and put all of those into my `C_Cpp.default.defines` setting, but I get the same behavior.

What is the recommended/most robust way of just getting VS Code to see what gcc sees? The above is a minimal example, but it's causing VS Code to fail to pick up type definitions from various system header files even though the code compiles fine.

Comment: Suggestion: ditch the stock C/C++ intellisense and replace it with Clangd. I found it to be a lot more robust, but you'll need to generate `compile_commands.json` for it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Nice. I ended up doing that.